# Laravel com firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

Queria saber se há alguma maneira de simular aquele listener do Firebase (que ainda não é compatível com PHP) pra receber as informações do banco em tempo real. Estou usando **Laravel**, resgato as informações pelo Controller e mando pra view via array. Sei que existe o **Broadcasting**, mas não sei se seria a opção certa nessa situação, também não sei muito bem como implementar. Um exemplo do funcionamento:

CONTROLLER:

```
function index(){
    $database = app('firebase.database');
    $drinks = $database->getReference('Drinks')->getSnapshot();

    return view('welcome', [
       'drinks' => $drinks->getValue()
    ]);
}
```

VIEW:

```
@foreach($drinks as $key => $drink)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell" data-title="Bebida">{{$drink['name']}}</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Preço">R$ {{sprintf("%01.2f", $drink['price'])}}</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Id">{{$key}}</div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Ações">
            <div class="container-buttons">
                <a href="delete/{{$key}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Excluir</button></a>
                <a href="edit/{{$key}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Editar</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Creio que não seja possível, pois as atualizações em tempo real do firebase precisam estar do lado do cliente...

> Observação: os listeners em tempo real não são compatíveis com a biblioteca de cliente PHP.

Recomendo que faça por javascript no cliente essa consulta.